Translating pretty-print code to format directives
I am writing pretty-printing code in the style of Common Lisp, the language. While I have the intuition that this code could be written more compactly using format directives, I still did not succeed to do so, so I am sharing my example and I am asking if someone is able to write a format directive with the same semantic.
CL-USER> (let ((properties
          '(:a "the letter a" :b "the letter b"
            :a-property-with-a-long-key "and a very long value")))
(pprint-logical-block (nil properties :prefix "(" :suffix ")")
  (loop (write-char #\()
    (pprint-indent :block 1)
    (write (pprint-pop))
    (write-char #\Space)
    (pprint-newline :linear)
    (write (pprint-pop))
    (write-char #\))
    (pprint-exit-if-list-exhausted)
    (pprint-indent :block 0)
    (write-char #\Space)
    (pprint-newline :linear))))
;; Ouput
((:A
  "the letter a")
 (:B
  "the letter b")
 (:A-PROPERTY-WITH-A-LONG-KEY
  "and a very long value"))
;; Return value
NIL

(The code above is certainly much more understandable than the yet-to-find format directive replacing it. However a format directive would work great when generating code on a ad hoc basis.)

If properties are nil, your code outputs ((NIL NIL))- is that intended?

Also, do you want to output conditional newlines, or each expression has to be on the new line (+ with indentation), as shown in your example?

Conditional (:linear) newlines, but I would also be fine with forced newlines. Most likely than not, the output will not fit on a line anyway. No properties should be just NIL instead of ((NIL NIL)) but this is not too important.

Try something like this:
(let ((properties '(:a "the letter a" 
                    :b "the letter b"
                    :a-property-with-a-long-key "and a very long value")))
  (format t "(~{(~s~& ~s)~^~&~@{ (~s~&  ~s)~^~&~}~})" properties))

Output:
((:A
 "the letter a")
 (:B
  "the letter b")
 (:A-PROPERTY-WITH-A-LONG-KEY
  "and a very long value"))

Used directives:

~{...~} iterates over elements of list
~@{...~} iterates over remaining elements from list
~s prints the element (= (write (pprint-pop)))
~& prints conditional new line (= pprint-newline) (replace with ~% for unconditional newline)
~^ stops if there are no other elements in list (= pprint-exit-if-list-exhausted)


Why is the ~@{...~} needed? Just (format t "(~{(~s~& ~s)~^~&~})" properties) produces the same output as far as I can tell.

Oh, wait... no, there is a difference in indentation.

That's great, thank you for your answer and your very detailed description. There is however an important difference with the code, which is that you do not use logical blocks "~:<" and
"~:>".
